# Supply a path for file editing in VIM?

Tags: vim, configuration

Is there a way to set a PATH-like sequence of directories to search for files in vim?  My project has C files split across many directories, and it would be nice to jump back and forth without remembering the full path each time.

For instance, if I have:

```
platform/drivers/uart.c
ui/display/menu.c
cpu/registers/regs.h
```

I would like to be able to set PATH to "platform/drivers:ui/display:cpu/registers".  Then when I want to switch to a file, I can just type:

```
:e uart.c
```

instead of

```
:e platform/drivers/uart.c
```

I understand that I can change the working directory, but then I have to type

```
:e ../../ui/display/menu.c
```

to get to another directory.

Alternatively, is there a better way to navigate a project like this than using :edit?

Comment: ctags are excellent, and I use them for jumping to symbols.  However in this case, I do want to select the file by name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, and it's called [`path`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27path%27). The way you use `path` is with the [`:find`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#%3afind) command: `:find menu.c` would search for menu.c in the directories in `path` and edit it. There are other commands that use `path`, like `:sfind` that opens the found file in a new split. See the [documentation of `path`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27path%27) for details and other commands that use it.

Another thing that may help you find your files is the [**-wildcard](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#starstar-wildcard) that can expand to any directory path. For example `:edit **/menu.c` will look for menu.c in subdirectories, so you don't have remember and type the full path.

Comment: I looked at `path`, but it doesn't seem to work with `:edit`.  If I am in a different working directory and type `:e uart.c`, it will create a new uart.c in the current directory, not find the uart.c in the path.  However, :e **uart.c seems to do what I want.  Thanks!